# This function only prints out the last value entered into the array

Tags: arrays, function, max, average, min

I need this function to print out the max, min, and average of all of the values entered into the array. I've run into the problem that the program will only print out the last value entered for the array. Ex. If I input 43, 78, and 23, it will only print 23 for the average, max, and min. What am I doing wrong to get this output?

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 float temptotal = 0;
 float averagetemp = 0;
 float temperatures[50];
 float average();
 void highest();
 void lowest();
 int main()
 {
 average();
 highest();
 lowest();
  }
 float average()
{
    float days = 0;
    cout << "Enter the number of days: ";
    cin >> days;
    if (days > 50)
    {
        cout << "You may only enter temperatures for 50 days." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the temperature for day number " << i << ": ";
        cin >> temperatures[50];
    }
            temptotal += temperatures[50];
            averagetemp = (temptotal / days);
            cout << "The average temperature is: " << averagetemp << endl;
            return temperatures[50];
}
void highest()
{
    float max = -9999999999999;
    if (temperatures[50] > max)
        max = temperatures[50];

    cout << "The highest temperature is: " << max << endl;
    }
    void lowest()
    {
            float min = 9999999999999;
            if (temperatures[50] < min)
                min = temperatures[50];
            cout << "The lowest temperature is: " << min << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing all inputs in the 50th element of the array.

Therefore last one overwrites all others.

This should work for averaging.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter the temperature for day number " << i << ": ";
    cin >> temperatures[i];
    temptotal += temperatures[i];
}
average = temptotal / days ;
```

this should work for max.

```
float max = -9999999999999;
for(  int i = 0 ; i < days ; i++ )
{
    if (temperatures[i] > max)
        max = temperatures[i];            
}
cout << max;
```

and do a similar thing for min too.

Comment: The code for the max and min doesn't work, I keep getting an error with the days variable.

Comment: Millet123, It was referring to temperatures[50] which is invalid. I editted User3946110's post the code for max should work now.

Comment: It isn't working still, I get an error saying that the days variable isn't initialized.

Comment: Really? Look through from where it's declared to where you're using it.
It looks OK in the code you posted but you've probably edited it somewhat by now. If you're still stuck after an hour repost a question.
Also look at where you're reading into.
BTW, days should be an int not a float. Indexing an array with a floating point number is dodgy. What do you think temperatures[2.5678] should return?